# Catch events with QRectF

Tags: python, events, pyqt, qgraphicsscene

I have a QGraphicsScene where I add QRectF objects anchored to QWidget objects in order to move them. I'd need to capture events or signals from the QRectF but the mousePressEvent method never runs.
These objects have a sort of balance and it would be hard to replace the QRectF with a QRect or a QGraphicsRectItem, because drawing the base rect in the scene only that class is accepted.

I also tried to implement the mousePressEvent method is GraphicBlock class (which is a QWidget) but nothing happens.

This is my QRectF

```
class BlockRect(QRectF):
def __init__(self, x, y, dim1, dim2, block_type):
    super(QRectF, self).__init__(x, y, dim1, dim2)
    self.block_type = block_type

def contains(self, point):
    if self.x() + self.width() \
       > point.x() > self.x() - self.width()/2:
        if self.y() + self.height() \
           > point.y() > self.y() - self.height()/2:
            return True
    return False

# Never called
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    print("click!")
    dialog = MyDialog(self.block_type)
    dialog.exec()
    super(BlockRect, self).mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)
```

And this is the method where I draw it:

```
    def draw_block(self, block_type):
    """Drawing a graphic clock with its properties"""

    # Setting the visible scene
    viewport_rect = QRect(0, 0, self.view.viewport().width(),
                          self.view.viewport().height())
    viewport = self.view.mapToScene(viewport_rect).boundingRect()
    start_x = viewport.x()
    start_y = viewport.y()

    # The initial point of each block is translated of 20px in order not to
    # overlap them (always in the visible area)
    point = QPoint(start_x + 20*(self.numBlocks % 20) + 20,
                   start_y + 20*(self.numBlocks % 20) + 20)
    transparent = QColor(0, 0, 0, 0)

    # Creation of the graphic block
    block = GraphicBlock(self.numBlocks, block_type, 0, self.scene)

    # Positioning the block
    proxy = self.scene.addWidget(block)
    proxy.setPos(point.x(), point.y())

    # Creation of the rect that will be parent of the QWidget GraphicBlock
    # in order to move it in the QGraphicsScene
    rect = BlockRect(point.x() + 10, point.y() + 10,
                     block.width() - 20, block.height() - 20,
                     block_type)

    # The rect is added to the scene and becomes the block's parent
    proxy_control = self.scene.addRect(rect, QPen(transparent), QBrush(transparent))
    proxy_control.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
    proxy_control.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
    proxy.setParentItem(proxy_control)
    block.set_rect(rect)

    self.blocks[self.numBlocks] = block
    self.numBlocks += 1
    self.update()
```

I really don't know or understand how i could capture events in some way.

Here it is my QWidget class, i.e. GraphicBlock, which do have event methods but doesn't execute them. I think I should control events from the QGraphicsScene object.

```
class GraphicBlock(QWidget):
"""QWidget that carries both graphical and logical information about the
layer node
"""

def __init__(self, block_id, block_type, block_data, scene):
    super(GraphicBlock, self).__init__()
    self.block_id = block_id
    self.block_type = block_type
    self.block_data = block_data   # Just to try
    self.scene = scene
    self.rect = None

    # Setting style and transparent background for the rounded corners
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    self.setStyleSheet(GRAPHIC_BLOCK_STYLE)

    # Block title label
    type_label = QLabel(block_type.name)
    type_label.setStyleSheet(BLOCK_TITLE_STYLE)

    # Main vertical layout: it contains the label title and grid
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.setSpacing(0)
    layout.addWidget(type_label)
    self.setLayout(layout)

    if block_type.parameters:
        # Creating the grid for parameters
        grid = QWidget()
        grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        grid.setLayout(grid_layout)
        layout.addWidget(grid)

        # Iterating and displaying parameters
        par_labels = dict()
        count = 1
        for par in block_type.parameters:
            par_labels[par] = QLabel(par)
            par_labels[par].setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            par_labels[par].setStyleSheet(PAR_BLOCK_STYLE)

            dim = QLabel("<dim>")
            dim.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
            dim.setStyleSheet(DIM_BLOCK_STYLE)

            grid_layout.addWidget(par_labels[par], count, 1)
            grid_layout.addWidget(dim, count, 0)
            count += 1
    else:
        type_label.setStyleSheet(ZERO_PARS_BLOCK_TITLE)
```

def set_rect(self, rect):
self.rect = rect

Comment: Sorry but I believe you've a lot of confusion about what QRect and QGraphicsItem are. You're saying that "it would be hard to replace the QRectF with a QRect or a QGraphicsRectItem". That doesn't make any sense: not only QRect and QRectF are almost the same thing (the difference is just about their coordinate system, which is integer or float based, respectively), but whenever you ["add" a QRect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addRect) to a QGraphicsScene, you **do** get a QGraphicsRectItem: «Creates and adds a rectangle item to the scene, and returns the item pointer.»

Comment: Also, QRect and QRectF classes have absolutely *no* mouse, keyboard or whatsoever event methods, and they even shouldn't: «The QRect[F] class defines a rectangle in the plane». It's just an abstract representation of a rectangle, it's not something that is drawn or used as an event manager. So, the question is: what are you *really* trying to do? You said you added some widget to the scene, why don't you implement the mouseevent in them? Can you share the code for those widgets?

Comment: I edited the question adding that cose. I tried to implement the mouseevent in the QWidget but it dind't work